# Querying all maps from an array in a document

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query all data from an array in Firestore, but the certain array is made of objects. This is what my DB looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkcap.jpg
You guys have any idea how I should do it?

This is the code I'm trying to achieve my goal with:

```
sawroomDB.collection("reservationsSecure").doc(todaysDate.getFullYear().toString()).get().then(doc => {
        tableAllReservationsBody.innerHTML = doc.data().allReservations;
        console.log(doc.data().allReservations)
    })
```

The output I'm getting printed is just "[object Object],[object Object]" and in the console I can see and browse the arrays

What I need is to see the whole information from the objects, just by calling the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`doc.data().allReservations` is going to be an array of objects, as you can see from the console output.  From what we can see in the screenshot, those objects contain at least one property called `booking`.  If you want reach into the first object and get the value of the booking property:

```
const allReservations = doc.data().allReservations
const r1 = allReservations[0]
console.log(r1)
const booking = r1.booking
```

Of course, you might want to iterate the `allReservations` array instead of blindly indexing into it.  But the point here is that each object just has that properties that you see in the console.  You'll be able to see better when you log each object individually as above, rather than trying to log the entire array, which might compress down the contents of each object from your view.